# Fill in interstitial data in counting series

Tags: excel, matlab, csv

I have several CSV files with 3 columns:

- Column 1 is an identifier
- Column 2 is a corresponding concentration and
- Column 3 is a volume.

The identifiers simply run in order from 1-950, but all are not present in each sample and therefore each CSV file.

Is there a way to use either Excel or MATLAB to fill in the numbers that are not present? This way when I combine them into 2D array they all line up together.

Currently it looks like:

```
Compound Name,Peak Value,Volume
1,627434.8768,5.50E+07
5,2.53E+07,5.11E+08
7,1.64E+07,3.07E+08
```

Ideally, it would be

```
Compound Name,Peak Value,Volume
1,627434.8768,5.50E+07
2,0,0
3,0,0
4,0,0
5,2.53E+07,5.11E+08
6,0,0
7,1.64E+07,3.07E+08
```

Comment: @zlinks - I've changed your edits, as they included a lot of unnecessary monospacing and bold/italic changes.  Be mindful that excessive use of these will distract the reader from the overall goal of the post.

Comment: @rayryeng thanks, will try to keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll provide a solution using MATLAB.  What you can do first is read in your data using [`csvread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html) but skip the first row as it contains headings.  After, create a 2D matrix where the first row is delineated from 1 to 950.  Next, use the first column of the data you read in through `csvread` and index into this 2D matrix so that you can store the corresponding rows for each identifier in this matrix.  When you're done, write this new matrix to a new file.

Of course, you'll need to open up the original file to get the headings first, write this to a new file then your data should follow after.  You can do this with [`fopen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html) to open up the file, then [`fgetl`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html) to retrieve the first line of the original file.

Let's say your file was called `test.csv`.  The code could look something like this:

```
M = csvread('test.csv', 1, 0); %// Parse through file starting from second row
out = [(1:950).' zeros(950,2)]; %// Create empty 2D matrix like before
out(M(:,1),2:3) = M(:,2:3); %// Populate the matrix and index into the right rows

fid = fopen('test.csv', 'r'); %// Open up the original file for reading
fid2 = fopen('out.csv', 'w'); %// Open up the output file for writing
first_line = fgetl(fid); %// Get the first line of the original file
fprintf(fid2, '%s\n', first_line); %// Write this first line to the output file
fprintf(fid2, '%d,%e,%e\n', out.'); %// Write the modified 2D array to file
fclose(fid); fclose(fid2); %// Close both of the files
```

The above code is self-explanatory with comments.  The output CSV file gets written one called `out.csv`.  However, the intricacy I will point you to is the second last line of code.  See how I am printing the first column to be integers (`'%d'` modifier), while the other numbers are in exponential notation (`'%e'` modifier) to satisfy your example you showed us above.  Also, MATLAB deals with data in **column-major** format, and so you actually need to write the **transpose** of the matrix to file (hence the `.'` operator).

Using your test data and the code above, here are the first 11 lines (10 data + row headings) seen in the output CSV file:

```
Compound Name,Peak Value,Volume
1,6.274349e+05,5.500000e+07
2,0.000000e+00,0.000000e+00
3,0.000000e+00,0.000000e+00
4,0.000000e+00,0.000000e+00
5,2.530000e+07,5.110000e+08
6,0.000000e+00,0.000000e+00
7,1.640000e+07,3.070000e+08
8,0.000000e+00,0.000000e+00
9,0.000000e+00,0.000000e+00
10,0.000000e+00,0.000000e+00
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I am getting an error on line 3:
`??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or
logicals.`
Any suggestions, unfortunately my MATLAB experience is fairly weak

Comment: Can you provide a link to a file that you used to run that code? That is more concerned with the way your input file is structured. Essentially, it means that your input file you read in has no data. It could also mean that the file doesn't exist. Make sure you are providing the correct path and name to the file.

Comment: [link] https://www.dropbox.com/s/ms5p80lvenbrp60/ki02.csv?dl=0
I have found if I use the MATLAB importer tool I can get it to work clumsily.

Comment: It doesn't work because you have blank entries and commas at the end of your file. I'm on my way home from work but I'll check it further soon. However try removing those and try the code again.

Comment: Error on my part, removed blank entries from code and it now works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: OK cool! Let me know if you run into more problems. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If your identifiers are always natural numbers, in Matlab you can do it with just indexing:

```
input = [1, 627434.8768, 5.50E+07
         5, 2.53E+07,    5.11E+08
         7, 1.64E+07,    3.07E+08];
output = zeros(max(input(:,1)), size(input,2));  %// initiallize with zeros
output(input(:,1),:) = input;                    %// fill in available values
```